# C# na form 2 não mostra a string na label

Tags: c#

Não entendo porque mas o Form 2 não mostra o texto do label no form 1.

form 1

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Username = textBox1.Text;
        HelloForm HF = new HelloForm();
        HF.Show();
        HF.Username = Username;
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

form 2

```
    public string Username { get; internal set; }

    private void HelloForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Text = "Hello " + Username;
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca a pergunta em português.

Comment: eu quero que no label 1 da form 2 apareça a string username da form 1

Comment: hehe, eu entendi o que você falou em inglês :P Mas o site é em português, entendeu?

Comment: obrigado eu não sabia editar para pt sou novo neste site só agora vi ali o botão de editar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa permitir que o label1 seja alterado por outra classe. Neste caso você deve alterar a propriedade Modifiers.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu caso não está funcionando porque a propriedade não possui o valor no momento que você a utiliza. Se você depurar, verá que no momento, Username possui o valor null. Neste caso indico você criar uma sobrecarga no construtor da classe.

```
public HelloForm(string _username)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Username = _username;
}
```

e depois pode simplificar o botão, usando o novo construtor.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelloForm HF = new HelloForm(textBox1.Text);
    HF.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Fiz o teste aqui e funcionou da forma que você precisa.

Comment: Já estava privado e é na label da form 2 não form 1

Comment: Então troca para public. Você quer acessar ela publicamente e não de forma privada.

Comment: Não funcionou..

Comment: Vê se ajuda agora.

Comment: ja da obrigado!!! mas nem tudo era perciso